# Sort objects in array by 2 attributes in Ruby with the spaceship operator

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, object, spaceship-operator

I have a `SizeMatters` class that creates an object from a given string. In order to sort these objects in an array, I've implemented the `<=>(other)` method. But the following code only helps the objects to be sorted by size. I also want the array to be sorted alphabetically.

```
class SizeMatters
  include Comparable
  attr :str
  def <=>(other)
    str.size <=> other.str.size
  end
  def initialize(str)
    @str = str
  end
  def inspect
    @str
  end
end

s1 = SizeMatters.new("Z")
s2 = SizeMatters.new("YY")
s3 = SizeMatters.new("xXX")
s4 = SizeMatters.new("aaa")
s5 = SizeMatters.new("bbb")
s6 = SizeMatters.new("WWWW")
s7 = SizeMatters.new("VVVVV")

[ s3, s2, s5, s4, s1 , s6, s7].sort #[Z, YY, bbb, xXX, aaa, WWWW, VVVVV]
```

What I want is this

```
[ s3, s2, s5, s4, s1 , s6, s7].sort #[Z, YY, aaa, bbb, xXX, WWWW, VVVVV]
```

How can I write `<=>(other)` so that objects in array can be sorted first by size and then alphabetically?

Comment: How is `['a', 'A']` to be sorted?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Just 'A' before 'a'

Comment: Note that since you are sorting an array of instances of your class, `sort` will return the same. To have it return an array of the associated strings you will need to tack on `.map(&:str)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define `<=>` like this:

```
   def <=>(other)
     [str.size, str] <=> [other.str.size, other.str]
   end
```

Comment: I just want to point out that the documentation is _extremely_ thorough on how this comparison works.

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E

Comment: ... and maybe think about nils, if they're possible, with something like  `[str.size || 0 , str || ""]`. I usually like to pop something like this into a separate `#sorter` method.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Except that there is no `NilClass#size` so you'd probably have better luck with things like `s = str.to_s; [s.size, s]`.

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to sort the strings by size and break ties by sortings strings of the same length by lexicographical ("dictionary") order. Yes, you will need to define `SizeMatters#<=>`, but it may be a mistake to define it for sorting, as that would prevent you from comparing stings in the normal way elsewhere in your class. Consider keeping your definition of `<=>` and use [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) for the sorting.

```
class SizeMatters
  include Comparable

  attr_reader :str

  def initialize(str)
    @str = str
  end

  def <=>(other)
    str.size <=> other.str.size
  end

  def sort_criteria
    [str.size, str]
  end

  def lexi_precede?(other)
    str < other.str
  end
end

[s3, s2, s5, s4, s1 , s6, s7].sort_by(&:sort_criteria).map(&:str)
  #=> ["Z", "YY", "aaa", "bbb", "xXX", "WWWW", "VVVVV"]

s1.lexi_precede?(s2)
  #=> false
```